# Undo float for mobile screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

On my desktop version I use float to set two divs next to each other.
On my mobile version one of these divs is not visible so I want to undo the float on the one that has it.

How do you 'undo' float in a media query? I tried float:none; and clear:both; but this didn't work. This is my css code;

```
             .float {
                      float:left;
                      padding-right:10px;
                  }

                @media (max-width: 900px) {
                .float {
                        float:none !important;
                            text-align:center;

                    }
                 }
```

And this is my html code;

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                    <img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="float">
                    <h1 style="padding-top:70px; padding-left:10px;" class="logo title">LIPSUM DOLOR</h1>
                    <h2 class="sub logo">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
                </div><!-- end col -->
</div><!-- end row -->
```

Now I'm using twitter's bootstrap, that's why I use the columns and rows. The first column with a width of 4 is not visible on xs screens (mobile) so shouldn't cause any trouble. It also doesn't have custom styling.

Comment: Did u try `float: none`?

Comment: Yes, I said so in my question, but thank you for helping.

Comment: Sorry I missed the line

Answer (score 3):

Your code for media query was wrong. It should be

```
.row{
    text-align:center;
}
.float {
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .float {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: The media query worked regardless, all the other classes in the media query worked accordingly. But I will change this. Problem is still not solved though. Setting a text-align:center on .row will set all the text on my whole layout centered, that is not what I want. I only want it centered on my mobile screens and only the image that has the class float.

Comment: I add the row styling is just an example for you to see the changes. Just don't put it, sorry about that. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2sP4e/

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice, because 1) notes the error in the media query, and 2) it dispenses with the totally unnecessary !important.

Comment: Anyway, you can't center an image by giving it `text-align:center`. You need `display:block; margin:0 auto;`. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sP4e/1/). One question though. Why konijntjes?

Comment: Err... I really don't know where it came from though. lol. If you set the logo as display:inline-block; then you can make both image and text centered by putting .row{text-align:center;}. I have update the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2sP4e/2/